# pdf of area of a circle

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

$X,Y$ are random variables with standard normal distribution (they are independent).
$W$ is the area of the circle that has center at $(0,0)$ and passes through $(X,Y)$.

What is the pdf of $W$?

I know that $r=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ but what I'm do from here?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the pdf of the *area* of the circle. The area is $pi r^2 = \pi(X^2 + Y^2)$. Do you know the distribution of the sum of the squares of standard normal variates?

Comment: I agree with M. Vinay, I doesn't make sense to talk about the pdf of a geometric object, it has to be a number; like its perimeter or radius or area.

Comment: @M.Vinay, how do I calculate the sum of $X,Y$??

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then it tells you something about the distribution of $X^2+Y^2$. Purely on base of the data in your question (no mentioning of independency) the pdf of $W$ is not determined yet.

Comment: @drhab, thank you! I add this information....

Comment: @drhab - It giving me direction but I still not understand how to use it... Can you help me more please?

Comment: @Yoar You have to do *some* work! You know that $W = \pi(X^2 + Y^2)$, and that $X^2 + Y^2 \sim \ldots ?$

Comment: What are $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$? Did you mean $\text{Exp}(1/2)$?

Comment: @M.Vinay, Sorry, my mistake... I'm little bit confuse...:-)